# Нужна ли запятая перед "кого"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "кого" в шуточной фразе: "Вот(,) кого я не люблю, так это всех"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая после ВОТ не нужна. В данном примере ВОТ - указательная частица, после которое знаков препинания не требуется: "Вот кого я не люблю, так это всех". Правда, высказывание несколько корявое. Но это уже совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: @olsa, это не корявое высказывание, это ирония. Или как там точно это фигура речи называется.

Comment: Я оценила :-))